# AS3 regex split

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I want to split a number using regex. I have  a number like `xyz` (`x` and `y` are single digits, `z` can be a 2 or three digit number), for example `001` or `103` or `112`. I want to split it into separate numbers. This can be done, if I'm not wrong by doing `split("",3)`; This will split the number (saved as string, but I don't think it makes difference in this case) `103` in an array with values `1`,`0`,`3`.
Since here it's easy,the fact is that the last number `z` may be a 2 or 3 digit number.
So I could have `1034`, `0001`, `1011` so on. And I have to split it respectively into `[1,0,34]` `[0,0,01]` `[1,0,11]`
How can I do that?

Thanks

Sergiu

Comment: how are we to tell how many digits the last element of the array should be.

Answer (score 3):

```
var regex:RegExp = /(\d)(\d)(\d+)/;
var n:Number = 1234;
var res:Array = regex.exec(n.toString()) as Array;
trace(res.join("\n"); /** Traces:
                        * 
                        * 1234
                        * 1
                        * 2
                        * 34
                        * 
                        * The first 1234 is the whole matched string 
                        * and the rest are the three (captured) groups.
                        */
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I was going the hard way...it was just possible to use substr to substract the charcaters I want and the put them in an array.

Comment: Put it as an answer and tick it so other people can learn from it.